# Accessing DynamoDB from client side using javascript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cordova, amazon-dynamodb

I am developing an HTML5 mobile application which I am planning to port to Android also using Phonegap. I want to use AWS DynamoDB for storing my users data. I know that amazon has a http api but it is too complicated. Some of my queries are

1. If I use the HTTP api, wouldn't it expose my credentials? (Same qquery for [dynode](https://github.com/Wantworthy/dynode))
2. What are the alternatives? I have a EC2 instance so hosting a server is not a problem.

I would appreciate your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect directly from your phone application, to dynamodb, you will risk exposing your credentials.

The general way to handle this is to have a json REST api through which the phone application can authenticate and make requests to the datastore. Your application would communicate with this api.

In this case, each user would likely have its own authentication to your server application.

Comment: So you mean that I should setup a JSON REST API on my server and through that server connect to AWS? I am considering using node.js?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Node.js or any platform you prefer can be used here.

Comment: Thanks @datasage. I have created a Node.Js API and its working fine.